# Why isn't my XML passing the XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an ASP page that generates an XML file based off of an XML page that was generated by a newer product.  The XML file contains GreenButton data (www.greenbutton.org). The two files look to me to be identical in structure, but it doesn't render correctly.  Since I cannot attach files, here are links to the XSLT and the two XML files:

XSLT: [GreenButtonDataStyleSheet.xslt](http://www.hawkfire.ca/GreenButtonDataStyleSheet.xslt)

Working XML: [10210000-0_Jun_1-Jun_12_Electric.xml](http://www.hawkfire.ca/10210000-0_Jun_1-Jun_12_Electric.xml)

Failing XML: [10006-0-20051101-20051201.xml](http://www.hawkfire.ca/10006-0-20051101-20051201.xml)

The XMLs can be tested here: [GreenButton.org Test Site](http://www.greenbuttondata.org/greentest.aspx)

Any assistance would be appreciated, even if it is to point me to the proper place to ask for help in this issue.

Comment: Adding the linked xslt code and xml files to your question preserves the value of the question when those links no longer work. It also increases the chances that the question will be answered.

Comment: Additionally, you should reduce your source and data files to the minimum size that still exhibit the problem.  111Kb of XSLT can't all be important to your question.  Thanks.

Comment: The answer below took only a few minutes to find. If you are doing any development in this area, you need to get yourself a good XML/XSLT developer's tool and debug by stepping through the transform. You would have easily found the issue documented below within the first few steps on the transform.

Comment: Thank you. I don't do a lot of XML development - I'm primarily a classic ASP/vbscript developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML you present as "broken" has a set of link elements at the top.

```
    <link rel="self" href="User/10006/UsagePoint/0"/>
<link rel="up" href="User/10006-0/UsagePoint/"/>
<link rel="related" href="User/10006-0/UsagePoint/0/MeterReading"/>
   <link rel="related" href="User/10006-0/UsagePoint/0/ElectricPowerUsageSummary"/>
```

If you examine the XSL, it uses the value of the href to lookup the corresponding section.

The "10006-0" in these do not exist. If you change these to "10006" the result formats correctly. That is, looking later in the XML file, you will not find "User/10006-0/UsagePoint/0/MeterReading", you will find "User/10006/UsagePoint/0/MeterReading" (without the "-0". So, whatever produced or added these "-0" in the top level links is broken. The result finds nothing and you render nothing. Below is a shot of the page obtained by removing the "-0" on these top level links.

[image]